# PLY using dynamic tokens

Tags: python, python-3.x, ply

I'm writing a program that can parse math papers written in .tex files. Here are what I want:

The program is supposed to detect the beginning, the end, sections, subsections, subsubsections, theorems, lemmas, definitions, conjectures, corollaries, proposition, exercises, notations and examples in a math paper and ignore the rest of the contents to produce a summary.

In the beginning the program is supposed to retain all characters until reaching token `MT`. In this case the lever should preserve the token and enter `ig` mode. Then it should ignore all characters unless it detects a theorem/lemma/definition/conjecture/corollary/example/exercise/notation/proposition, in which case it temporarily enters the `INITIAL` mode and retain it or a (sub/subsub)section in which case it should temporarily enter the `sec` mode.

`\newtheorem{<name>}{<heading>}[<counter>]` and `\newtheorem{<name>}[<counter>]{<heading>}` are detected as `TH ptext THCC ptext THC ptext` and `TH ptext THCS ptext THSC ptext THC` respectively where `ptext` is a bunch of `TEXT`.

```
import sys
import logging
from ply.lex import TOKEN

if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    raw_input = input

tokens = (
'BT', 'BL', 'BD', 'BCONJ', 'BCOR', 'BE', 'ET', 'EL', 'ED', 'ECONJ', 'ECOR', 'EE', 'SEC', 'SSEC', 'SSSEC', 'ES', 'TEXT','ITEXT','BIBS','MT','BN','EN','BEXE','EEXE','BP','EP','TH','THCS','THSC','THCC','THC',
)

states = (('ig', 'exclusive'), ('sec', 'exclusive'), ('th', 'exclusive'), ('tht','exclusive'),('thc','exclusive'))

logging.basicConfig(
    level = logging.DEBUG,
    filename = "lexlog.txt",
    filemode = "w",
    format = "%(filename)10s:%(lineno)4d:%(message)s"
)
log = logging.getLogger()

th_temp = ''
thn_temp = ''
term_dic = {'Theorem':'','Lemma':'','Corollary':'','Definition':'','Conjecture':'','Example':'','Exercise':'','Notation':'','Proposition':''}
idb_list = ['','','','','','','','','']
ide_list = ['','','','','','','','','']
bb = r'\\begin\{'
eb = r'\\end\{'
ie = r'\}'
def finalize_terms():
    global idb_list
    global ide_list
    if term_dic['Theorem'] != '':
        idb_list[0] = bb + term_dic['Theorem'] + ie
        ide_list[0] = eb + term_dic['Theorem'] + ie
    if term_dic['Lemma'] != '':
        idb_list[1] = bb + term_dic['Lemma'] + ie
        ide_list[1] = eb + term_dic['Lemma'] + ie
    if term_dic['Corollary'] != '':
        idb_list[2] = bb + term_dic['Corollary'] + ie
        ide_list[2] = eb + term_dic['Corollary'] + ie
    if term_dic['Definition'] != '':
        idb_list[3] = bb + term_dic['Definition'] + ie
        ide_list[3] = eb + term_dic['Definition'] + ie
    if term_dic['Conjecture'] != '':
        idb_list[4] = bb + term_dic['Conjecture'] + ie
        ide_list[4] = eb + term_dic['Conjecture'] + ie
    if term_dic['Example'] != '':
        idb_list[5] = bb + term_dic['Example'] + ie
        ide_list[5] = eb + term_dic['Example'] + ie
    if term_dic['Exercise'] != '':
        idb_list[6] = bb + term_dic['Exercise'] + ie
        ide_list[6] = eb + term_dic['Exercise'] + ie
    if term_dic['Notation'] != '':    
        idb_list[7] = bb + term_dic['Notation'] + ie
        ide_list[7] = eb + term_dic['Notation'] + ie
    if term_dic['Proposition'] != '':
        idb_list[8] = bb + term_dic['Proposition'] + ie
        ide_list[8] = eb + term_dic['Proposition'] + ie
    print(idb_list)
    print(ide_list)
```

Here are some of the parsing functions:

```
def t_TH(t):
    r'\\newtheorem\{'
    t.lexer.begin('th')
    return t

def t_th_THCS(t):
    r'\}\['
    t.lexer.begin('thc')
    return t

def t_tht_THC(t):
    r'\}'
    if term_dic.has_key(thn_temp) == False:
        print(f"{thn_temp} is unknown!")
    elif len(th_temp) == 0:
        print(f"No abbreviation for {thn_temp} is found!")
    else:
        term_dic[thn_temp] = th_temp
        print(f"The abbreviation for {thn_temp} is {th_temp}!")
    th_temp = ''
    thn_temp = ''
    t.lexer.begin('INITIAL')
    return t

def t_th_THCC(t):
    r'\}\{'
    t.lexer.begin('tht')
    return t

def t_thc_THSC(t):
    r'\]\{'
    t.lexer.begin('tht')
    return t

@TOKEN(idb_list[0])
def t_ig_BT(t):
    t.lexer.begin('INITIAL')
    return t

@TOKEN(ide_list[0])
def t_ET(t):
    t.lexer.begin('ig')
    return t

def t_INITIAL_sec_thc_TEXT(t):
    r'[\s\S]'
    return t

def t_th_TEXT(t):
    r'[\s\S]'
    th_temp = th_temp + t.value()
    return t

def t_tht_TEXT(t):
    r'[\s\S]'
    thn_temp = thn_temp + t.value()
    return t

def t_ig_ITEXT(t):
    r'[\s\S]'
    pass

import ply.lex as lex
lex.lex(debug=True, debuglog = log)
```

Here are the errors:
    `ERROR:`       `/Users/CatLover/Documents/Python_Beta/TexExtractor/texlexparse.py:154: No regular expression defined for rule 't_ET'`

I don't know why the regular expression defined for 't_ET' etc using @TOKEN do not work.

Comment: It appears you forgot to ask a question. "*Here are what I want*" is not enough to describe what you want help with.

Comment: @Johan Oh I didn't notice that! Really thanks! Basically what happened is that I want some regular expressions to depend on variables. This apparently did not work.

Comment: No problem, just want to make sure people don't misinterpret what you need help with :)

Answer (score 1):

Ply is a parser *generator*. It takes your parser/lexer description and compiles a parser/lexer from it. You cannot change the description of the language during the parse.

In this particular case, you might be better off writing a streaming ("online") scanner. But if you want to use Ply, then you will be better off not trying to modify the grammar to ignore parts of the input. Just parse the entire input and ignore the parts you're not interested in. You'll probably find that the code is much simpler.

Comment: I see. Thanks! How am I supposed to write a streaming scanner? I don't have to use PLY or even Python. Other tools and languages are fine as long as they work.

Comment: Excuse me...but what are streaming scanners?

Comment: @Ying: A scanner which produces tokens as it reads the input. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_algorithm for the use of the word "streaming". Or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML for its application to XML parsing.